# Gnuplot not filling the lines in 3D graphics

Tags: gnuplot

I'm ploting with gnuplot but in the 3D graphics some areas are not completed, empty.

The question is simple: how to force it to fill the empty areas ?

[image]

Commands that I'm using:

```
fit (a**-(x**(y**b))) './Tabela_perda_01_MOS_70ms_com_sameq_GOP_30_2_Foot.txt' using 1:2:3:(1) via a,b


set clabel '%8.2f'
set key right

set xlabel "X"
set ylabel "Y"
set zlabel "Z"

set xrange [0:1]
set yrange [2:20]
set zrange [0:1]

set isosample 11,20

set pointsize 0.5
set style line 1 lt 1 lw 2 pt 3 lc rgb "black"
set style line 2 lt 1 lw 1 pt 3 lc rgb "black"

splot "./Tabela_perda_01_MOS_70ms_com_sameq_GOP_30_2_Foot.txt" using 1:2:3 notitle w points ls 1, (a**-(x**(y**b))) w l ls 2
```

Comment: Can you post some example code with which you made this plot?  `set pm3d` may help you get started.

Comment: Hi Andyras, I put the examples. I did your suggestion "set pm3d" and it just have colors after